Managed Package Apex (invoked by Flow) not working in Professional Edition
I am an ISV and my app has a lot of Apex code. I am testing everything in a Pro Suite org to see if we are compatible. So far everything is functional and working as expected. One thing that does not appear to work is invokable Apex that is kicked off in a Flow. Both the Flow and Apex class are part of my managed package but I still am seeing the following error when it runs:
FLOW_ELEMENT_ERROR|Unsupported action type: APEX |FlowActionCall

It seems like the org is treating the invoked Apex like custom developed code specific to this org when in fact everything is controlled by my managed package. After reading the documentation here it is still unclear why/if this is unsupported.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/dev_packages_apex_ge_pe.htm
I created a case with Salesforce but was curious if anyone else has seen this before.

I look forward to your self-answer based on what support tells you.
